# Add variables to a variable Observable <>

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have an Observable variable :

```
messages: Observable<Message[]>;
```

I would like to add variables to this Observable variable. Since this is a collection of Message: Message [], I would like to add Message variable to it :

```
const newMessage = new Message(objMessage);
```

I do not see how to do this, I tried this but it dosen't work because it's for no-Observable variable:

```
newThread.messages = [newMessage];
```

Or this :

```
newThread.messages.subscribe((message: Message) => {
  newThread.messages = message;
});
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
EDIT

I initialize my variable messages in my thread.model.ts :

```
messages: Observable<Message[]> = new Observable<Message[]>();
```

And I initialize my variable newThread.messages in an other service chat.service.ts :

```
newThread.messages.next(newMessage);
```

But it puts me this error :

```
Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Observable<Message[]>'
```

Plunker Link :

```
https://plnkr.co/edit/aNzWu2ShO55bk3fRJ5ya?p=catalogue
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
EDIT

I just realized that it does not work as I would like.
This does not work when there is more than one message. With what I had done, the second message deletes the first message. While I want the variable *thread.messages* to contain a stack of messages.

So I tried using the .next method, but that puts me in error.

```
export class Thread {
  id: string;
  messages: BehaviorSubject<Message[]>;
}

const newThread: Thread = new Thread(objMessage.id, [newUser],objMessage.title);
const newMessage = new Message(objMessage);
newThread.messages.next([newMessage]);


Cannot read property 'next' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined
```

Or this :

```
private subject = new Subject<Message[]>();

this.subject.next([newMessage]);

thread.messages.subscribe((messages: Message[]) => {
   messages = this.subject.asObservable();
});
```

Do you know why ?

Comment: You could do `Observable.of([newMessage])` or you could use `.next` method to push data into Observable stream.

Comment: @pankaj
I can't use .next with this type of variable : Observable<Messsage[]>

Comment: Because you haven't declared Observable yet, you should be intializing observable before pushing value into it like `messages: Observable<Message[]> = new Observable<Message[]>()`

Comment: @pankaj
I have edited my post

Comment: Please do push `newMessage` in Observer like 
 `newThread.messages.next(newMessage);`

Comment: @pankaj
It puts the same error

Comment: Can you please create a plunker and add it in question?

Comment: @pankaj
I put the plunker link, I hope it works because this is the first time I use plunker. I have not added all my project, I put the 2 most important files.

Comment: @pankaj
Thanks, finally it works with the solution Observable.of([newMessage])

Comment: Great, how you did that?

Comment: `newThread.messages = Observable.of([newMessage]);`
`messages: Observable<Message[]>;`


Just like that :)

Comment: @PankajParkar
In the end, it does not work. I republished an answer. I am trying to use the .next method

Comment: Not sure, what you did tried different thing in new answer?

Comment: @PankajParkar
I tried adding a Subject variable in order to use the .next method
But I do not see how to add this variable to my Observable.

Comment: Can you please create plunker? I'd be happy to jump on it

Comment: @PankajParkar
https://plnkr.co/edit/aNzWu2ShO55bk3fRJ5ya?p=catalogue

Comment: I need a working plunker.. so that I can correct it.

Comment: @PankajParkar
I can not put all my project, there are too many files.
Which file do you need ?

Comment: Reproduce a problem with minimal relevant code. Thats it.. and then put it in plunker

Comment: @PankajParkar
https://plnkr.co/edit/St720Ot9AN50YsKVilil?p=catalogue
I have simplified and added files.
My problem is in the function _addNewMessage_, where I would add messages to the variable _threds.messages_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .next() method add data in observable stream data by adding a new behaviour subject

Comment: In the end, it does not work. I republished an answer. I am trying to use the .next method